# Cannot Commit to TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

From within Visual Studio I try to commit to a tfs repository. I can use the Server Browser and update my sources. But when I click onto "pending changes" I receive the following error:

> System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The
>   composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is
>   provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for
>   more detailed information.
>
> 1) Cannot create an instance of type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.LabelSaveException'
>   because a constructor could not be selected for construction. Ensure
>   that the type either has a default constructor, or a single
>   constructor marked with the
>   'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportingConstructorAttribute'.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot activate part
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.LabelSaveException'.
>   Element:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.LabelSaveException
>   -->  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.LabelSaveException
>
> Resulting in: Cannot get export
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.LabelSaveException
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorerSection")'
>   from part
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.LabelSaveException'.
>   Element:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.LabelSaveException
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorerSection")
>   -->  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.LabelSaveException
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine
>   engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart
>   part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()
>   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()
>   at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export
>   export)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ExportFactoryCreator.LifetimeContext.GetExportLifetimeContextFromExport[T](Export
>   export)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ExportFactoryCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<CreateStronglyTypedExportFactoryOfTM>b__6()
>   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory`1.CreateExport()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerSectionHost.Create()

I CAN still check in my changes, but the "comment" area is missing. How to solve this?

(UPDATE): I receive the same error when I try to display the "Changeset Details"

But no Error when displaying the History

Comment: After "dealing with it" for some months, suddenly yesterday everything works fine. Might be solved by an Update